# Can't figure out the following error

Tags: php, mysql

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cart\admin\addtocart.php on line 13

Here is my code,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $pid=$_POST['id'];
        $wasFound=false;
        $i=0;
        if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1){
            $_SESSION["cart_array"]=array(0=>array("item_id"=>$pid,"quantity"=>1));
        }else{
            foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item){
                $i++;
                while(list($key,$value)=each($each_item)){
                if($key=="item_id" && $value==$pid){
                    array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"],$i-1,1,array(array("item_id"=>$pid,"quantity"=>$each_item['quantity']+1));
                    $wasFound=true;
                }
            }
        }
        if($wasFound==false){
            array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"],array("item_id"=>$pid,"quantity"=>1));
        }
    }
    header("location:cart.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: You are missing a ) at the end of the statement

Comment: You are missing a ) at the end of the statement where `array_splice ` is used

Comment: Please, please, *please* use spaces in between operators. It is painful to read code without spaces. See [here](http://docs.typo3.org/flow/TYPO3FlowDocumentation/stable/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartV/CodingGuideLines/PHP.html#php-code-formatting) for a guide on how to format your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have missed last closing brace ')' on below line

```
array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"],$i-1,1,array(array("item_id"=>$pid,"quantity"=>$each_item['quantity']+1)));
```